# MySQL subquery with LIMIT

Tags: mysql, subquery, limit

I have read over similar posts on using subqueries and can't figure out how to apply it to my needs.

I have two drug tables:

`Generics` with fields `GenericID` and `GenericName`

and `DrugCaseCounts` with fields `GenericID` (links to `Generics`), `DrugName` and `Cases`

The `Generics`.`GenericName` is the active ingredient in the drug, e.g. fluoxetine, and the `DrugCaseCounts`.`DrugName` is the brand name, e.g. Prozac.  `DrugCaseCounts`.`Cases` is the number of Case reports where that brand name appears.  There can be more than 10 `DrugCaseCounts` records (different brand names) for one `Generics`.`GenericID`.

I want to produce a list that shows:

`Generics`.`GenericID`, `Generics`.`GenericName`, `DrugCaseCounts`.`DrugName`, `Cases`

listing the top 10 `DrugCaseCounts`.`DrugName` records, GROUPED BY `GenericID` in descending order by Cases.

I know this requires a subquery on the DrugCaseCounts table, but I can't figure out how to state it.

Comment: Can there be more than on DrugCaseCounts record per GenericID?

Comment: Yes, Generics holds the parent "generic" drug, and DrugCaseCounts holds the brand name drugs plus the number of Cases that took that brand name.  E.g. Prozac (which you've probably heard of) is a brand name for fluoxetine.  You will often see this in ads as Prozac (fluoxetine).  Fluoxetine also is marketed under 11 other labels including Fluctin, Fluox, Ladose, Lovan and Sarafem. The programming request is to provide a list of the top 10 brand name drugs for each generic, listed in descending Case count order.